# PyQt4 @pyqtSlot: what is the result kwarg for?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

By reading [this](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator), two questions came up:

1.
It says

> it is sometimes necessary to explicitly mark a Python method as being
>   a Qt slot

While I always use the @pyqtSlot decorator because it says:

> Connecting a signal to a decorated Python method also has the
>   advantage of reducing the amount of memory used and is slightly faster

I ask myself: in which specific cases is it necessary?
and: Are there any advantages of not using the @pyqtSlot decorator?

2.
The result keyword argument, what is its purpose?

```
@pyqtSlot(int, result=int)
def foo(self, arg1):
    """ C++: int foo(int) """
```

It looks like the return value's type, but AFAIK you cannot retrieve return values when emitting signals.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It is faster because of PyQt architecture. PyQt converts the python slots to C++ slots, in order to communicate with the Qt framework. When you explicitly mark a Python method as a Qt slot and provide a C++ signature for it, the PyQt code doesn't have to guess the C++ signature itself, as it is already specified. This may enhance performance on heavy projects.
2. The return value is only needed when you want to call the slot as a normal function.

**Edit**: It seems that the [`QMetaObject.invokeMethod`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) method executes a slot and uses it's return value.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! So I suppose there's no advantage of not using the decorator i.e. <ALWAYS USE IT> ?

Comment: use it on heavily used slots. If it's a basic slot that doesn't do much and isn't called much, there's no need in the decorator. It enhances the script a bit, but it won't be noticeable on simple functions.

Comment: OK, so I would say, always use it because it enhances code readability (with syntax highlighting)

Comment: A note about the `result=` kwd arg: it is _required_ for the PyQt D-Bus bindings if your slot returns a value. Thus, for a function you want to expose via D-Bus that takes a string and returns an int, you would decorate the function with `pyqtSlot(str, result=int)`. If you don't include `result=int`, invocations via D-Bus will not return a value. I only mention it because I recently spent a large chunk of time debugging this very problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731709/how-does-one-expose-methods-and-properties-on-dbus-using-a-qdbusabstractadaptor.)