# Access python function from javascript in QWebView

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qwebview

I am writing a Python/PyQt4 application that generates and displays a page in a QWebView widget.  The page includes javascript code that I would like to be able to call functions returning data from the python application.

So far I can call functions that do not return data (using the pyqtSlot decorator), and call functions that do take parameters by exposing them as properties (using the pyqtProperty decorator).  What I haven't worked out how to do is to call a python function with parameters, that returns data.

The question 9615194 explains how to do this from C++, but I cannot see how to transfer this to PyQt4.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not using the `result=` keyword to specify the return value in your `pyqtSlot` decorator?

```
@pyqtSlot(str, result=str)
def echo(self, phrase):
    return self.parent().echo(phrase)
```

I ran afoul of this myself recently. No errors are generated if you omit `result=`, the method just silently returns nothing. Pretty maddening 'til I figured it out. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731709/how-does-one-expose-methods-and-properties-on-dbus-using-a-qdbusabstractadaptor) for a worked example.