# Drag and Drop in pyqt4 with modifier keys

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

Consider the following minimal example. How can I modify it, that it does something else, when a modifier key is pressed during the drop event as indicated in the comment in the code snipped below. Suppose you drop a file from nautilus or something like that to my example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyDropLabel(QLabel):
    myDroppedSignal = pyqtSignal(str)    
    myDroppedSignalModified = pyqtSignal()    

    def __init__(self,text):
        super(MyDropLabel, self).__init__(text)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            s = e.mimeData().urls()[0].path()
            self.myDroppedSignal.emit(s)
        e.accept()

##if a modifier key, for example shift or ctrl was pressed to something else and emit myDroppedSignalModified




class MyWidget(QWidget):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
         self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
         self.setLayout(self.hlayout)
         self.label = MyDropLabel("Drop something here")
         self.hlayout.addWidget(self.label)
         #self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

         self.label.myDroppedSignal.connect(self.myDroppedHandler)

    def myDroppedHandler(self,s):
        self.label.setText(QString(s))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    da = MyWidget()
    da.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, for example, set a `self.keyIsPressed` state by `installEventFilter( QObject * filterObj )` to filter the `QEvent.KeyPress` that you define.

This is an example using `QApplication.keyboardModifiers`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class droppableLabel(QLabel):
    fileDropped = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(droppableLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()

        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()

        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))

            self.fileDropped.emit(links)

        else:
            event.ignore()

class droppableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(droppableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = droppableLabel(self)
        self.label.fileDropped.connect(self.on_label_fileDropped)
        self.label.setText("Press CTRL/SHIFT/None and drop some files here")
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QSize(40, 100))

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)

    @pyqtSlot(list)
    def on_label_fileDropped(self, fileNames):
        droppedFiles = [    fileName
                            for fileName in fileNames
                            if os.path.exists(fileName)
                            ]

        if droppedFiles:
            keyModifiers = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
            if keyModifiers == Qt.ShiftModifier:
                print "SHIFT"
                formatter = "\n"                

            elif keyModifiers == Qt.ControlModifier:
                print "CTRL"
                formatter = ","

            else:
                print "NONE"
                formatter = "|"

            self.label.setText(formatter.join(droppedFiles))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = droppableWidget()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need some more details since I am a beginner. Can you implement your idea in my minimal example?

Comment: @student checkout [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14022417/1006989), I added an example that will to illustrate it

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and modified it for my actual code and it works pretty well. Since I am a pyqt4 beginner and want to learn something new it would be great if you could explain the `@pyqtSlot` thing in your example a bit more in detail.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272951/pyqt4-pyqtslot-what-is-the-result-kwarg-for and I think it explains what I wanted to know about @pyqtSlot. So it is not necessary in your example?

Comment: Not really, it will work without the `pyqtSlot` you might as well skip that part