# python pyqt return value slot

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to return a value from a slot when running a thread but I can not get the result

```
class Foo(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(result=int)
    def getFloatReturnInt(self, f):
        return int(f)

class functions(QThread):
    trigged = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.trigged.connect(self.foo.getFloatReturnInt)

    def run(self):
        string = self.trigged.emit(1)
        print(string)
        time.sleep(3)

thread = functions()
thread.start()
time.sleep(5)
```

The value returned is None and I do not know what the reason is since I follow the details of the official pyqt page, Where is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "the value returned is None"? You're never getting the return value of the slot in this code. You *do* get the return value of the `emit(1)` call, which is probably `None`. Is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4 @pyqtSlot: what is the result kwarg for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272951/pyqt4-pyqtslot-what-is-the-result-kwarg-for)

Comment: Yes, always return None, where is the problem?